# Constructor / Destructor Linking Error

Tags: c#, c++, windows, visual-studio, clr

I have a project (that creates a dll), say test.dll, where I am not exporting the constructor and destructor of a class, say TestClass, out in the dll. This is because I have some factory functions that are supposed to be invoked to create and destroy objects of TestClass. This design works perfectly fine in stand alone examples that I create where I try to use objects of TestClass from test.dll.

However when I link this test.dll (or the .lib in my case since I am using Visual Studio) to a project in our production module, I get weird linking errors pointing to the constructor and destructor that it could not find for TestClass. I know for a fact that I don't call new / delete, or create any stack instance of TestClass anywhere in the project. The production module uses C#/CLR/CLI along with C++ I think. The only way to get around is for me to export the constructor and destructor for TestClass. This is undesirable by design.

Is this situation familiar to anyone? Can some one point to what might be the issue?

This is the error that I get:

```
Error   5264    error LNK2028: unresolved token (0A000BA3) "public: virtual __thiscall BE::TestClass::~TestClass(void)" (??1TestClass@BE@@$$FUAE@XZ) referenced in function "public: virtual void * __thiscall BE::TestClass::`vector deleting destructor'(unsigned int)" (??_ETestClass@BE@@$$FUAEPAXI@Z)  AMBestDetailBridge.obj  BEBase

Error   5373    error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual __thiscall BE::TestClass::~TestClass(void)" (??1TestClass@BE@@$$FUAE@XZ) AMBestDetailBridge.obj  BEBase
```

Thanks!

Comment: please show us a minimal example that displays your problem

Comment: Are you ever creating stack instances of the class? Those need the constructor and destructor too.

Comment: Its kinda tricky to show an example. This is because the problem doesn't occur when I create a simple application. There is something about our system, and I find it in only one of our projects. I know they have some CLR code hanging in there. I am trying to figure out if it might have to do with that. I am not very familiar with CLR.

Comment: I am not creating stack or heap instance. The design itself is such that the factory methods have to be used.

Comment: Is TestClass get inherited in your production module?

Comment: The linker will point at an `*.obj` file. That tells you which `*.cpp` file is invoking the constructor accidentally. You can generate a `*.cod` file to search for the call.

Comment: TestClass is basically an abstract interface class. Its inherited in the test.dll. In the production module, it only gets used. It does not get inherited in the production module.

Comment: I know the linking error points to a .obj in my production module. But that is basically the file where I include the header containing the TestClass definition, and Factory methods. I do not explicitly call the constructor or destructor here.

Comment: You can temporarily make the constructor/destructor private and ask your client DLL to compile. Then they should get a compiler error if they accidently use the constructor directly/via a base-class

Comment: Suggest to generate assembler listing for production module that causes linking errors. This could help to check is ctor/dtor are really called in code somewhere. Also you could try /FORCE linker option to ignore errors (not guaranteed to create valid executable).

Comment: I would say @PermanentGuest's suggestion is a good idea, have you tried that?

Comment: could you at least show TestClass code and the complete error that you are getting during the linking process?

Comment: Your error is interesting. It is about the destructor. If the factory is creating the objects, are you sure that it is the responsibility of the factory to destroy them as well?

Comment: @PermanentGuest : Yes I have two factory methods. One to create TestClass objects and another to destroy them. It works perfectly fine for any other stand alone example, or a lot of the other projects in our production code. There is this one project where I notice this weird error. The irony is, I just include the header for TestClass, and link the lib file corresponding to test.dll in the production module. For some reason, this causes a linking error since it is trying to call the destructor. It is very weird!

Comment: Since you already know which obj cause the link error, go to that cpp,    remove certain code (like the factory destroy method call), you can find out which call is the root cause, then look into that, or post it here if you still not sure.

Comment: I already did what I would think is logical. Now I am inclined to believe that it is some sort of a compilation setting which forces constructor/destructor to be available at linking. Is there a case where this might be true?

Answer (score 1):

The link error says you are calling destructor through delete [], so it is most probably that in your production module, you have certain code:

```
TestClass* pTest = ...
delete pTest;
TestClass* pTestArray = ...
delete[] pTest;
```

Of course , it might be not that obvious, in case of smart pointers:

```
SmartPtr<TestClass> spTest = ...
// delete called automatically when out of scope.
```

Allocate in one module and delete in another will put yourself in potential risk - because the 2 modules may use different heap for memory allocation (say you redefine new operators), it is lucky that this problem is exposed in link time, not run time.